# showing an image with Graphics View widget

Tags: python, qt-designer

I'm new to qt designer and python. I want to created a simple project that I should display an image.
I used "Graphics View" widget and I named it "graphicsView". I wrote these function:

```
def function(self):
    image=cv2.imread('C:/Users/Hamid/Desktop/1.jpg',1)
    self.show_frame_in_display(image)

def show_frame_in_display(self,frame):
    image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0],
                  frame.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
    self.graphicsView.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
```

but It gives this error:

```
File "C:/Users/Hamid/Documents/untitled/hamid.py", line 54, in show_frame_in_display
self.graphicsView.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
AttributeError: 'QGraphicsView' object has no attribute 'setPixmap'
```

what should I do? thank you.

Comment: You can use `label` to display an image instead...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. could you tell me how I should use it?

Comment: I just posted my answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `QtGui.QLabel` to display images as well, this way:

```
label_Image = QtGui.QLabel(frame)
image_path = 'c:\image_path.jpg' #path to your image file
image_profile = QtGui.QImage(image_path) #QImage object
image_profile = image_profile.scaled(250,250, aspectRatioMode=QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, transformMode=QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation) # To scale image for example and keep its Aspect Ration    
label_Image.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image_profile))
```

Impplementing the above code in your original code:

```
def function(self):
    image_path='c:\image_path.jpg' #path to your image file
    self.show_frame_in_display(image_path)

def show_frame_in_display(self,image_path):
    frame = QtGui.QWidget() #Replace it with any frame you will putting this label_image on it
    label_Image = QtGui.QLabel(frame)
    image_profile = QtGui.QImage(image_path) #QImage object
    image_profile = image_profile.scaled(250,250, aspectRatioMode=QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, transformMode=QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation) # To scale image for example and keep its Aspect Ration    
    label_Image.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image_profile))
```

Comment: excuse me, I used your code but I got this error:  'MyApp' object has no attribute 'image_profile'

Comment: In qt designer I named the label to "label_image". where should I use it?

Comment: Ok...what is the name of the `Widget` or `frame` you've put your `label_image` on it?

Comment: excuse me, I'm confused. in qt designer I dragged a label and I changed its objectname to "lable_image" and saved it and I am not going to read the images from memory. could you guide me more, please?

Comment: Is the image you want to display, going to be the same during your whole program execution, or it will change depending...?

Comment: I want to  capture the image from camera then process it. finally I should show the output images.

Comment: I found its solution. Image must be RGB . gray images can't be used.

Comment: What did you use for that? `Graphic View` widget?

Comment: I used a label. It's very simple. Thanks Khalil Ammour for your help and attention.